# Storing novel features with scikit-learn

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, bioinformatics, feature-extraction

I'm working on bioinformatics sequence research which involves extracting various sequence based features from many sets of sequences (FASTA files). 
I generate various features for the sequences, and process each sequence individually (I'll be working with tens of thousands of sequences). I'm a novice at programming and handling data.

What would be the BEST way to store and output (i.e save to a matrix in a csv file) the generated features?

The names of the features are important to me, so i'll want them, in addition to needing their outputted order to be consistent for each seperate sequence.

I planned to store the features (per sequence) with a dictionary, since I understand that scikit learn's "[dictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html)" function might work for this. 
However - A dict is unorganized, and I'll be extracting the features for each sequence individually, writing that out, then extracting from the next sequence - Will it keep the same order when writing out? (All the features are numerical and continious, but many may have a value of 0, and some would have a vector as an output [E.G - 400 frequency counts of overlapping bigrams).

Thanks!

(I'm mainly concerned with the I/O and not getting the output of the features mixed. )

Comment: There is something called an ordered dictionary, which might help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Any idea if this works with the sklearn method(S)?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't used them in the context of scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks anyway - I'm looking for an answer from someone who's used said tools. (Since my context for asking is "What's the easiest/best way to do this" + "How to do this")

Comment: A `DictVectorizer` leans a mapping of strings to indices, so it is effectively ordered.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to do this would be either `pandas` or `dill`.  I think `pandas` would be your better option but you can use both.

```
import pandas as pd
import dill
```

If you're trying to store matrices with labels you're talking about `DataFrames`.  You can easily make a `DataFrame` in `pandas` from an array or dictionary by doing `DF = pd.DataFrame(array_object)`  you can set the column names by `DF.columns = ["label1","label2",etc.]` and index values by the same method `DF.index = ["A","B",etc.]`.  Then you can just store it into a csv/tsv by doing `DF.to_csv("filename.tsv",sep="\t")` (I usually do tab separated b/c commas are weird) that writes it to a spreadhseet format that you can easily retrieve later by doing `pd.read_table("filename.tsv",sep="\t")`.  Another way you can do it is using `dill` which stores your environment variable into a file that you can load later (I do this for more complicated objects but it works for DataFrames or matrices or whatever you want).  If you had that `DataFrame` from the `matrix/array` you could just do `dill.dump(DF,open("DF.obj","wb"))` to store that object and then retrieve it later with `dill.load(open("DF.obj","rb"))`.

I would do the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` method since you can open the stuff in Excel (biologists love excel).  If they are just matrices, then using `dill` to store the objects is overkill.  It's a good tool to have in your repertoire if you're making stuff for yourself but passing along stored `dill` objects to other people can get nasty.